# How to split json string in c# and store in separate variables

Tags: c#, json, string, split

I want to split following string using c#

```cs
string clnt_metadata="{itc:ITC}{id:56}"
```

I want output like this:

```cs
string itc="ITC"
string id="56"
```

Comment: This string is not valid Json. Can you change the string ? If no go with regexp.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deserialize multiple json in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57478405/how-to-deserialize-multiple-json-in-c)

Answer (score -3):

Use `var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<objectName>(clnt_metadata)`

```
public class objectName
{
   public string ITC {get; set;}
   public string id {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: @J Alcantara with your code this exception will occur `{"Error parsing Infinity value. Path 'itc', line 1, position 6."}`

Comment: That is because your string is invalid Json. It needs to be `{itc:"ITC"}`

Comment: then how to convert specified string into json and then read and split it to get output as mentioned above

Comment: The correct JSON format must be like this: {
 "itc":"ITC",
 "id":"56"
} Then you can simply call obj.ITC and obj.id

Answer (score -3):

```
line = reader.ReadLine();
while (line != null)
{
    string[] words = JsonSplitString(line);
    string json = words[1];
    writer.WriteLine("{0}", json);
    line = reader.ReadLine();
}
```