# How to deserialize multiple json in C#?

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.android

I'm loading some information to my  Xamarin application through multiple json strings. When I run the application, it gives me this error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[APIPost]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List
>    that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
>   Path 'postid', line 1, position 9.'

Code to get the json:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var result = await client.GetStringAsync($"{APIConfig.Uri}/post/getPost/{APIConfig.Token}/{User.ID}/{User.Token}");
List<APIPost> response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<APIPost>>(result);

foreach (APIPost post in response)
{  //Code  }
```

Class APIPost:

```
class APIPost
{
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string postid { get; set; }
    public string userid { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
    public string captation { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string likes { get; set; }
}
```

This is the json I get:

```
{
    "postid": "2",
    "userid": "2",
    "image": "asdasdasd",
    "captation": "asdasd",
    "location": null,
    "date": "2019-07-29 20:24:28",
    "likes": "4"
}{
    "postid": "1",
    "userid": "2",
    "image": "susfdfjsadv",
    "captation": "This is just a test.",
    "location": null,
    "date": "2019-07-29 19:58:04",
    "likes": "2"
}
```

Comment: That JSON is not valid.

Comment: To forestall any further questions along the same lines, no, you cannot coax json.net to deserialize this as it isn't valid json. If the server that returns this to you us saying application/json, then this is a bug in the backend because this is not JSON. It may *look* like JSON, but it isn't.

Comment: Additionally, it might be simple enough in the above case to try to do some string replacing to add a comma in the right place, some brackets around the whole thing, but this is just a ticking timebomb as you get an item with a captation [sic] of "This is just a {secret}{not-so-secret} test", and it'll change the data as well. Or someone adds a newline between the two seemingly json-like objects and your string replace doesn't work any more. Fix the backend, everything else is a hack and a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: I am not going to post this as an answer, as the only **correct** answer here is that the backend is wrong, fix the backend, but I did in fact manage to [coax Json.net into deserializing it](https://gist.github.com/lassevk/3ec7e05a05f21c39bd5f964d071c4537), piece by piece. **This is not an answer, you should not use it**, fix the backend, you still don't have valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with C# or with the JSON serialization library you're using.  The JSON you're receiving from the server **is invalid**.  As such, no standard JSON parsing library can be expected to successfully parse it.  You'll either need to write your own, or correct the JSON to be valid.

A valid object would look like:

```
{
  "postid": "2",
  "userid": "2",
  "image": "asdasdasd",
  "captation": "asdasd",
  "location": null,
  "date": "2019-07-29 20:24:28",
  "likes": "4"
}
```

And a valid array of objects would look like:

```
[
  {
    "postid": "2",
    "userid": "2",
    "image": "asdasdasd",
    "captation": "asdasd",
    "location": null,
    "date": "2019-07-29 20:24:28",
    "likes": "4"
  },
  {
    "postid": "1",
    "userid": "2",
    "image": "susfdfjsadv",
    "captation": "This is just a test.",
    "location": null,
    "date": "2019-07-29 19:58:04",
    "likes": "2"
  }
]
```

There's no such thing as "multiple JSON" within the same structure.  You either have a valid structure or you don't.  You can certainly have multiple structures, but you can't have them all mashed together into one like that.

In short... fix the server-side code to send a valid response.

Answer (score 0):

Have you any control over the source of that json?
You need to provide something like:

```
[
    {...},
    {...}
]
```

And you will be fine

Answer (score -1):

As @lasse-v-karlsen says in a comment, the server should be fixed but there's a way to parse this with Newtonsoft.Json (in case we're in one of those JSON-streaming scenarios):

```
using (var file = new StreamReader(@"D:\Temp\test.json", Encoding.UTF8))
using (var reader = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader(file))
{
    reader.SupportMultipleContent = true;

    var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault();
    
    serializer.Deserialize(reader).Dump();
    while (reader.Read())
        serializer.Deserialize(reader).Dump();
}
```

In case you're not fond on adding the dependency to json.net, then I've cooked a very simple JSON splitter:

```
IEnumerable<string> SplitJsonStream(string jsonString)
{
    IEnumerable<string> splitJsonStreamInner(char? head, string tail, uint braceNestingLevel, bool insideSubString, string acc)
    {
        if (!head.HasValue)
        {
            if (braceNestingLevel != 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("jsonString seems to be invaid");
            yield break;
        }
    
        char? newHead = null;
        string newAcc = null;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tail))
        {
            newHead = tail.First();
        }
        if (head.HasValue)
        {
            newAcc = acc + head.Value;
        }
        var newTail = newHead == null ? null : tail.Substring(1);

        if (!insideSubString && head == '"') {
            foreach(var subAcc in splitJsonStreamInner(newHead, newTail, braceNestingLevel, true, newAcc))
                yield return subAcc;
            yield break;
        }
        if (insideSubString)
        {
            if (head == '"')
            {
                foreach (var subAcc in splitJsonStreamInner(newHead, newTail, braceNestingLevel, false, newAcc))
                    yield return subAcc;
                yield break;
            }
            foreach (var subAcc in splitJsonStreamInner(newHead, newTail, braceNestingLevel, insideSubString, newAcc))
                yield return subAcc;
            yield break;
        }

        if (head == '{')
        {
            foreach (var subAcc in splitJsonStreamInner(newHead, newTail, braceNestingLevel + 1, insideSubString, newAcc))
                yield return subAcc;
            yield break;
        }
        else if (head == '}')
        {
            if (braceNestingLevel == 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("jsonString seems to be invalid");
            var newNestingLevel = braceNestingLevel - 1;
            if (newNestingLevel == 0) {
                yield return newAcc;
                newAcc = String.Empty;
            }
            foreach (var subAcc in splitJsonStreamInner(newHead, newTail, newNestingLevel, insideSubString, newAcc))
                yield return subAcc;
            yield break;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var subAcc in splitJsonStreamInner(newHead, newTail, braceNestingLevel, insideSubString, newAcc))
                yield return subAcc;
            yield break;
        }
    }

    jsonString = jsonString.Trim();
    if (jsonString == string.Empty)
        yield break;
    if (!jsonString.StartsWith("{"))
        throw new ArgumentException("jsonString should start with {");
    if (!jsonString.EndsWith("}"))
        throw new ArgumentException("jsonString should end with }");

    foreach (var sub in splitJsonStreamInner(jsonString.First(), jsonString.Substring(1), 0, false, String.Empty))
        yield return sub;
}
```

The proof that the above works is this unit test:

```
[Fact()]
public void JsonSplitterTests()
{
    Assert.Empty(SplitJsonStream(String.Empty));

    Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => SplitJsonStream("x").Count()); // not startswith {
    Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => SplitJsonStream("{x").Count()); // not endswith }

    var fooJson = "{ \"foo\": 1 }";
    var splitted = SplitJsonStream(fooJson);
    Assert.Equal(1, splitted.Count());
    Assert.Equal(fooJson, splitted.ElementAt(0));

    var barJson = "{ \"bar\": 2 }";
    splitted = SplitJsonStream(fooJson + barJson);
    Assert.Equal(2, splitted.Count());
    Assert.Equal(fooJson, splitted.ElementAt(0));
    Assert.Equal(barJson, splitted.ElementAt(1));

    var bazJson = "{ \"baz\": 3 }";
    splitted = SplitJsonStream(fooJson + barJson + bazJson);
    Assert.Equal(3, splitted.Count());
    Assert.Equal(fooJson, splitted.ElementAt(0));
    Assert.Equal(barJson, splitted.ElementAt(1));
    Assert.Equal(bazJson, splitted.ElementAt(2));

    // ends with bad nesting level
    Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => SplitJsonStream("{{x}").Count());
    Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => SplitJsonStream("{x}}").Count());

    // edge case
    Assert.Equal(1, SplitJsonStream("{ \"foo\": \"{\" }").Count());

    //whitespace in front
    Assert.Equal(2, SplitJsonStream("\n{ \"foo\": 1 }{ \"bar\": 2 }").Count());
    Assert.Equal(2, SplitJsonStream("\r\n{ \"foo\": 1 }{ \"bar\": 2 }").Count());
    Assert.Equal(2, SplitJsonStream("\t{ \"foo\": 1 }{ \"bar\": 2 }").Count());
    Assert.Equal(2, SplitJsonStream(" { \"foo\": 1 }{ \"bar\": 2 }").Count());
    //whitespace at the end
    Assert.Equal(2, SplitJsonStream("{ \"foo\": 1 }{ \"bar\": 2 }\n").Count());
    Assert.Equal(2, SplitJsonStream("{ \"foo\": 1 }{ \"bar\": 2 }\r\n").Count());
    Assert.Equal(2, SplitJsonStream("{ \"foo\": 1 }{ \"bar\": 2 }\t").Count());
    Assert.Equal(2, SplitJsonStream("{ \"foo\": 1 }{ \"bar\": 2 } ").Count());
    //whitespace in the middle
    Assert.Equal(2, SplitJsonStream("{ \"foo\": 1 }\n{ \"bar\": 2 }").Count());
    Assert.Equal(2, SplitJsonStream("{ \"foo\": 1 }\r\n{ \"bar\": 2 }").Count());
    Assert.Equal(2, SplitJsonStream("{ \"foo\": 1 }\t{ \"bar\": 2 }").Count());
    Assert.Equal(2, SplitJsonStream("{ \"foo\": 1 } { \"bar\": 2 }").Count());
}
```